# Find P(B) given the following values:

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability

P(A) = 0.56

P(B|A) = 0.85

P(¬B|¬A) = 0.32

What is P(B)?

Please answer using at least two decimal places.

The correct answer is supposed to be 0.78 but I am completely stumped on finding this. Would really appreciate a breakdown of the process. Please help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're given numbers that relate to $B$, so starting with those and see what falls out might be a good idea. We insert into the respective formulas to get:
$$
0.85 = P(B\mid A) = \frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}\\
0.32 = P(\lnot B\mid \lnot A) = \frac{P(\lnot B \cap \lnot A)}{P(\lnot A)}
$$
This lets you find the probabilities 
$$P(B\cap A)\\P(\lnot B \cap \lnot A) = 1-P(B\cup A)$$ You should now have a formula which lets you combine these two along with $P(A)$ to find $P(B)$. And if not, then drawing a Venn diagram and marking the regions you now know the probability for should make it evident which ones need to be added / subtracted to give you $P(B)$.

Comment: I'm sorry but the part "(¬∩¬)=1−(∪)" still does not make sense to me. I'm new to probability and would really appreciate if you could dive a little deeper into this

Comment: @EakjotHundal Drawing a Venn diagram may help. The size of the entire Venn diagram is $1$, and $\lnot B\cap \lnot A$ and $B\cup A$ together make up all of it. So together they make $1$, meaning either of them is $1 -{}$ the other.

Comment: Could you break this down in numbers for me @Arthur? The Venn diagram is not making sense to me as I understand better with numbers. For (∩) I got 0.476 and for (¬∩¬) I got 0.1408. I don't know where to go from there

Comment: @EakjotHundal From your $P(\lnot B\cap \lnot A)$, what is $P(B\cup A)$? And finally, you should have a formula relating all four of $P(B\cap A)$, $P(B\cup A)$, $P(B)$ and $P(A)$. You know three of these numbers, which is enough to find the fourth.

Comment: I do not have that formula, that is what I am struggling with.

Comment: @EakjotHundal Well, then. We can derive it. It's usually framed as a way to calculate $P(B\cup A)$, and thus it starts with $P(B\cup A) = \cdots$. And a first naive attempt would be to put $P(B) + P(A)$ on the other side, and be done ($P(B\cup A)$ does, after all, mean the probability that $A$ happens or that $B$ happens). However, this isn't quite right. What problem does $P(B\cup A) = P(B) + P(A)$ have? (For instance, try to think about various cases where this clearly cannot be true.)

Comment: You are a lifesaver, Arthur. Thank you for your time and especially for your patience with me.